# Unable to locate package. Не устанавливает ни один пакет

Tags: ubuntu, apt

`Sudo apt update` выводит `All packages are up to date.` Но ничего не устанавливает. Использую `ubuntu server` на `raspberry pi.`
Я удалил свой файл `sources.list` и создал снова для того, чтобы исправить проблему, и я начал получать сообщение об ошибке

> `Apt-cache policy` — вывод:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  release a=now
Pinned packages:
```

> `apt-cache policy python2` — вывод:

```
N: Unable to locate package python2
```

Comment: Покажите что вы делаете и что получается

Comment: Все. Пробовал python потом python2. И кучу других пакетов.

Comment: Не «опишите своими словами», а «покажите конкретные команды и конкретный результат их выполнения»

Comment: Sudo apt install python2 вывод: reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python2

Comment: Покажите вывод `apt-cache policy` и `apt-cache policy python2`. Только не в комментариях, а отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: `Я удалил свой файл sources.list` — ну так восстановите.

Comment: После восстановления появилась ошибка.

Comment: И что там сецчас?